# Python3.Descriptor.Class

Tags: python-3.x, python-descriptors

Hello i have simply task, but i am stuck again:

How can i use variable from class into descriptor?

I have `commission` variable from parent class and i need use it into descriptor while calling `set`: `self.amount = int(amount) * int(commission)`

How can i do this?

Thank you!

Full code bellow:

```
class Value():
    def __init__(self):

        return

    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type):
        return self.amount

    def __set__(self, obj, amount, commission):
        self.amount = int(amount) * int(commission)


class Account:

    def __init__(self, commission):
        self.commission = commission

    amount = Value(self.commission)

new_account = Account(0.1)
new_account.amount = 100

print(new_account.amount)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right code is below:

```
class Value():
    def __init__(self):
        return

    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type):
        return self.value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        self.value = value * (1 - obj.commission)


class Account:
    amount = Value()

    def __init__(self, commission):
        self.commission = commission


new_account = Account(0.1)
new_account.amount = 100

print(new_account.amount)
```

The trick that, when you call `__set__` on descriptor you pass obj inside, and you can call any variable or method as usual obj.xxx, that is basic i know but i am really noob with OOP.

Comment: I still feel like this isn't what is wanted, since it's storing the amount on the descriptor without and link to the Account object, so every Account object will share the same amount.